# which one is faster? - PHP query

Tags: mysql, performance

which one is faster? - PHP query

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT beli FROM user"));
```

or

```
$count = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT COUNT(beli) FROM user"));
```

or

```
$count = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user")); //since id is primary index
```

or

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT id FROM user")); //since id is primary index
```

why?

Comment: Welcome to SO. How could we possibly know, without access to your DB? Why don't you just run the queries and see which is quicker?

Comment: MySQL queries will be faster when using more times, in this case, as they are cached.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal command is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FROM user
```

I doubt if you want the `_assoc` API; you just want a scalar.

Your first and last queries gather one column from each row and shovels them over to the client.  The client then looks at how big the array is and gives you that as the count.  A lot of wasted work.

Using `COUNT(x)` semantically requires checking `x` for being `NOT NULL` before counting the row.  This is extra effort.

Using `COUNT(*)` simply counts the row in the simplest way possible.  (Note: `*` is not interpreted the same as in `SELECT *...`, where it refers to "all columns.)

Implementation:

`COUNT(*)` -- Find the smallest `INDEX` and walk through it.

`COUNT(beli)` -- Find the smallest index containing `beli`; if no such index, then use the table.  The table is likely to be larger than any secondary index.

`COUNT(id)` (assuming `PRIMARY KEY(id)`) -- In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s) are silently tacked onto the end of the columns specified by the `INDEX` definition.  This provides a way to get to all the columns from a secondary index.  Hence, `COUNT(id)` is probably identical to `COUNT(*)`.  (I don't know whether `id` is unnecessarily checked for `NOT NULL`.)